# Terence Tao, Analysis I, Thm. 5.5.9, Least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Terence Tao, Analysis I, 3e, Thm. 5.5.9:

> **Theorem 5.5.9** (Existence of least upper bound)**.** Let $E$ be a non-empty
>   subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If $E$ has an upper bound, (i.e., $E$ has some
>   upper bound $M$), then it must have exactly one least upper bound.

In the proof it says that

> (...) Now we show it [$S := \text{LIM}_{n \rightarrow \infty} (m_n - 1)/n$] is a least upper bound. Suppose $y$ is an
>   upper bound for $E$. Since $(m_n - 1)/n$ is not an upper bound, we
>   conclude that $y \ge (m_n - 1)/n$ for all $n \ge 1$.

But from  my understanding, if $y$ is an upper bound for $E$, then all elements in $E$ are smaller than or equal to $y$. And since $(m_n - 1)/n$ is not an upper bound, there are elements $x$ in $E$ such that

$$
(m_n - 1)/n < x \le y.
$$

If $y > (m_n - 1)/n$, then $y \ge (m_n - 1)/n$.

But why is equality used here? Is it some sort of trick to make use of

> (...) if $a_n \le x$ for all $n \ge 1$, then $\text{LIM}_{n
> \rightarrow \infty} \; a_n \le x$

in a following step of the proof?

Comment: What are $m_n$?

Comment: $m_n$ is an integer, s.t. $L < m \le K$ where $K/n$ is an upper bound of $E$, and $L/n$ is not. With $\mathbb{Z} \ni n \ge 1$.

Comment: Is your problem with the existence of the lub in the first place, or its unicity (that latter part is much easier)? Cannot really comment on the details of the book: I don't have it, so I don't know its definitions etc.

Comment: It's about existence and you are right that it's hard to make a statement without having the full context. Somebody posted the [complete proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3268257/172142), but it still lacks the definitions and exercises the proof references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that can be said is that $(m_n -1)/n \leq y$; that is by definition. Given the fact that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ the element $(m_n -1)/n$ is *not* an upper bound we can deduce that there is strict inequality.

In the following sentence he uses Exercise 5.4.8, which essentially says

> (...) if $a_n \le x$ for all $n \ge 1$, then $\text{LIM}_{n
> \rightarrow \infty} \; a_n \le x$

Here the result is true regardless of whether $a_n \le x$ or $a_n < x$ for all $n \ge 1$. In short, it does not matter whether to write strict or non-strict inequality; both are valid and the conclusion is the same.

---

By the way

> if $a_n < x$ for all $n \ge 1$, then $\text{LIM}_{n
> \rightarrow \infty} \; a_n < x$

is NOT true. Consider the sequence $(\frac{-1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Here each element is strictly smaller than $0$, but the limit equals $0$.

---

Also, the statement

> And since $(m_n - 1)/n$ is not an upper bound, there are elements $x$ in $E$ such that 
>   $$ (m_n - 1)/n < x \le y.$$

is only true because $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered. In a general partially ordered set this is not nessecarily the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elaborate answer! Helped me a lot and it's clear and nicely put. You're mentioning a definition in the first sentence. Where can I find it?

Comment: The definition of an upper bound of $E$. In Tao's book that's definition 5.5.1

Comment: The definition states that "We have that $M$ is an upper bound for $E$, iff we have $x \le M$ for every element $x$ in $E$". But $(m_n - 1)/n$ is not necessarily an element of $E$.

Comment: @MaxHerrmann I see, my mistake. Since $(m_n -1)/n$ is not an upper bound and $y$ is an upper bound, $(m_n-1)/n > y$ is false. Hence $(m_n-1)/n \leq y$ is true. To see this, assume $(m_n-1)/n > y$ to be true. Then $\forall e \in E: (m_n-1)/n > y \geq e$. Hence $(m_n-1)/n$ was an upper bound. Contradiction.

Comment: $y$ is upper bound $\Leftrightarrow$ $(\forall x \in E) x \le y$, whereas $y$ is no upper bound $\Leftrightarrow$ $(\exists x \in E) x > y$.

Comment: Yes, that's true. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97925/discussion-between-max-herrmann-and-g-chiusole).